# The name 'RegisterViewModel' does not exist in the current context. Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages

In the pages folder of my Blazor app, I created a 'register' page which is referring to the 'RegistrationViewModel' in the ViewModels folder. I cannot figure out why it's only the registration page that is giving an error

> RegisterViewModel does not exist in the current context

The squiggly lines appear in the phrases "RegisterViewModel" and "HandleValidSubmit".

The rest of the 7 pages that I created are OK with no errors. I have checked for spelling mistakes, checked with using directives with no success. What could I have missed? Let me know if I should post more code. Thanks

```
@page "/register"



<div class="mt-5 row">
    <div class="card col-12 col-lg-6 mr-auto ml-auto p-3">
        <h3 class="card-title">Register</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
            <EditForm Model="@RegisterViewModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
                <div class="input-group col mt-2">
                    <label class="col-12 col-md-4 p-0" for="firstName">First name:</label>
                    <InputText id="firstName" class="col-12 col-md-8 login-field" @bind-Value="RegisterViewModel.FirstName"></InputText>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group col mt-2">
                    <label class="col-12 col-md-4 p-0" for="lastName">Last name:</label>
                    <InputText type="lastName" class="col-12 col-md-8 login-field" @bind-Value="@RegisterViewModel.LastName"></InputText>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group col mt-2">
                    <label class="col-12 col-md-4 p-0" for="email">Email:</label>
                    <InputText id="email" class="col-12 col-md-8 login-field" @bind-Value="RegisterViewModel.Email"></InputText>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group col mt-2">
                    <label class="col-12 col-md-4 p-0" for="userName">Username:</label>
                    <InputText id="userName" class="col-12 col-md-8 login-field" @bind-Value="RegisterViewModel.UserName"></InputText>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group col mt-2">
                    <label class="col-12 col-md-4 p-0" for="password">Password:</label>
                    <InputText id="password" type="password" class="col-12 col-md-8 login-field" @bind-Value="RegisterViewModel.Password"></InputText>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group col mt-2">
                    <div class="offset-md-4">
                        <button class="m-2 p-2">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </EditForm>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Folder structure]

Something probably worth mentioning is the Authentication service class has errors as well. the squigglies are on 'AuthenticateAsync' and 'RegisterAsync' and the error message

> 'IClient' does not contain a definition for 'RegisterAsync' and no accessible extension method 'RegisterAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IClient' could be found.

```
    {
        private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;

        public AuthenticationService(IClient client, ILocalStorageService localStorage, AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider) : base(client, localStorage)
        {
            _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Authenticate(string email, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = new AuthenticationRequest() { Email = email, Password = password };
                var authenticationResponse = await _client.AuthenticateAsync(authenticationRequest);

                if (authenticationResponse.Token != string.Empty)
                {
                    await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("token", authenticationResponse.Token);
                    ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)_authenticationStateProvider).SetUserAuthenticated(email);
                    _client.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authenticationResponse.Token);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> Register(string firstName, string lastName, string userName, string email, string password)
        {
            RegistrationRequest registrationRequest = new RegistrationRequest() { FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName, Email = email, UserName = userName, Password = password };
            var response = await _client.RegisterAsync(registrationRequest);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.UserId))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public async Task Logout()
        {
            await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync("token");
            ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)_authenticationStateProvider).SetUserLoggedOut();
            _client.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please try  `Unload` and then click on `clean the solution` finally `Reload` the projects again. I hope it might resolve your problem. Let me know the update.

Comment: If that doesn't works then please share your folder structure and data controller, from where you are binding your views, that might help us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Unload, clean, reload did not resolve the problem.

Comment: If you comment this method and view other then this does your project encountered any issue?

Comment: I commented out the methods and tried commenting out the register.razor.cs file as well, no change in the project. The problem still not resolved

Comment: Does it means even you get rid of this whole page still you are getting this error right?

Comment: I haven't seen any reference of `RegisterViewModel`   on your page as you are using this after this  `@page "/register"` you should add this reference. It should be like this `@using BlazorApps.Data
@inject RegisterViewModel RegisterViewModel`

Comment: Right. For both register.razor.cs and  AuthenticationService.cs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236644/discussion-between-atamakit-and-md-farid-uddin-kiron).

Comment: anything that has reference on your view should be added above. just think of a namesapace. it should resolve your problem